# ValueError: Height and Width of image, mask or masks should be equal.disable shapes check by setting is_check_shapes=False of Compose class

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, albumentations

I would like to mention that the shape of image before transformation is:

|  | Shape |
| --- | --- |
| Original image | (360, 640, 3) |
| Original mask | (360, 640) |
| Transformed image | (320, 320, 3) |
| Transformed mask | (320, 320) |

and `img_trans` is defined as

```
img_trans = A.Compose([
    A.Resize(a_config.INPUT_IMAGE_HEIGHT, a_config.INPUT_IMAGE_WIDTH)],
    is_check_shapes=False
)
```

The code snippet is:

```
def image_mask_transformation(image, mask, img_trans, aug_trans=None, normalize=True,
                              var_min=10, var_max=400):

    
    
    print("Original image shape:", image.shape)
    transformed = img_trans(image=image, mask=mask)
    image = transformed["image"]
    mask = transformed["mask"]
    print("transformed image shape:", image.shape)
    # image, mask still uint 8 in 0, 255 range
```

But I am getting an error:

```
ValueError: Caught ValueError in DataLoader worker process 0.
Original Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/torch/utils/data/_utils/worker.py", line 308, in _worker_loop
    data = fetcher.fetch(index)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/torch/utils/data/_utils/fetch.py", line 51, in fetch
    data = [self.dataset[idx] for idx in possibly_batched_index]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/torch/utils/data/_utils/fetch.py", line 51, in <listcomp>
    data = [self.dataset[idx] for idx in possibly_batched_index]
  File "/content/drive/MyDrive/Colab Notebooks/CRACK500/tool/dataset.py", line 131, in __getitem__
    image_store, mask_store = image_mask_transformation(image, mask, self.img_trans, aug_trans=self.aug_trans,
  File "/content/drive/MyDrive/Colab Notebooks/CRACK500/tool/dataset.py", line 40, in image_mask_transformation
    transformed = img_trans(image=image, mask=mask)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/albumentations/core/composition.py", line 195, in __call__
    self._check_args(**data)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/albumentations/core/composition.py", line 286, in _check_args
    raise ValueError(
ValueError: Height and Width of image, mask or masks should be equal. You can disable shapes check by setting a parameter is_check_shapes=False of Compose class (do it only if you are sure about your data consistency)..
```

I am not sure whether I am getting the error because initially a 3rd dimension is there for image and not for the mask. Hence I have tried to add the `is_check_shapes=False` while defining `img_trans` but I am still getting the error.

Can you suggest whether and where I should add `is_check_shapes=False` or the error can be solved in any other way?

Comment: What version of the albumentations library are you using in your project? 
I'm unable to reproduce [your error in this repl with 1.3.1](https://replit.com/@oluwafemisule/Albumentations#main.py)

Comment: Hello, I am using the version 1.3.1

Comment: Can you edit your question and provide the stack trace? 
The error that your shared mentions a `DataLoader` but there is nothing about a `DataLoader` in your code snippet.

Comment: I have pasted the whole error now

Comment: I have used WORKER =1

Comment: Can you confirm the shape of the original image and the mask one more time? The error should only happen if the `image.shape[:2]` is not `mask.shape[:2]`

Comment: Original image shape: (360, 640, 3)
Original mask shape: (360, 640)
transformed image shape: (320, 320, 3)
transformed mask shape: (320, 320)
Original image shape: (360, 640, 3)
Original mask shape: (360, 640)
transformed image shape: (320, 320, 3)
transformed mask shape: (320, 320)

...... like this

Answer (score 0):

This is old now, but I had a problem where I was changing the dimensions of my image/mask before I performed the transforms. In my case, I was converting my images to channel first before transforming in my pytorch Dataset.

I had this:

```
def __getitem__(self, idx):
  ...
  if self.channel_first:
        image = np.transpose(image, (2, 0, 1)).astype(np.float32)
        mask = np.transpose(mask, (2, 0, 1)).astype(np.float32)

    if self.transform:
        transformed = self.transform(image=image, mask=mask)
        image = transformed["image"]
        mask = transformed["mask"]
```

when I should have had this:

```
def __getitem__(self, idx):
   ...

    if self.transform:
        transformed = self.transform(image=image, mask=mask)
        image = transformed["image"]
        mask = transformed["mask"]

    if self.channel_first:
        image = np.transpose(image, (2, 0, 1)).astype(np.float32)
        mask = np.transpose(mask, (2, 0, 1)).astype(np.float32)
```